# What is “default indexed property” in CLR/C#?

Tags: c#

I am reading "Framework Design Guidelines" book and I am puzzled by one of the rules (p.142) "Do not use non-default indexed properties."

I am confused, for several reasons -- indexed property should not mean indexer, but if it is about a property what is default property (auto one?), if this is a typo ("indexe**R** property"), and it is about indexers, I found some hints, that maybe indexer with single `int` parameter is called a default one (is it?), but in such case C# does not forbid other ones.

I am unable to decipher this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In some languages (e.g. *Delphi*) you can define *named indexed property(ies)*, e.g.

```
  type 
    TMyCollection = class(TObject)
    private
      ...
    protected 
      function GetItem(idx: LongInt): LongWord; virtual;
    public
      // Named ("Items") indexed (note "idx") property 
      property Items[idx: LongInt]: LongWord read GetItem; 
    end;
```

CLR *supports* this construction

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms229061(v=vs.100).aspx

however, it doesn't *recommended* to use such a construction, and some languages (*C#* being an example) *enforce* this guideline. All we are allowed in C# is *nameless* (*default*) index property - indexer.

Comment: So default indexer exists in C# because it uses `this` keywords before specifying the parameters, and non-default would is with name other than `this`? Am I correct? Named/anonymous somehow are more clear terms for me :-).

Comment: You're right, and when we call indexer, e.g. `myList[i]` we don't use any *name* (compare with *Delphi* example above: `MyCollection.Items[i]`)

Answer (score 1):

C# [Indexers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x16t2tx.aspx) are always default [indexed properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms229061(v=vs.100).aspx). It is not possible to create a non-default indexed property in C#. In Visual Basic, it's perfectly possible to create non-default [properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bc3dtbky.aspx) that use indexes.

Since there's no way for a C# program to make use of a non-default indexed property, that's *why* the framework design guidelines advise against creating them - so that C# and VB code can interoperate.

Comment: @greenoldman - I'm not sure where you're looking where optional arguments come into this. I've linked to three different documents.

Comment: Thank you, but I couldn't figure out what makes an indexer default or non-default.

Comment: @greenoldman - well, if you're just looking at C#, you won't be able to, because you cannot create a non-default indexed property in C#. The reason it's called the default indexed property is because it's the one that is accessed without *naming* the property. E.g. `myObject[1]` accesses the default property of `myObject`. *if* C# supported non-default indexed properties, then you'd have `myObject.NonDefaultProperty[1]` or something like that.

Comment: Thank you, the choice of word "default" completely misled me.

Comment: @greenoldman - blame it on a *lot* of legacy from VB. Pre .NET VB had a concept of default properties - and they didn't even have to be indexed (this second part is thankfully removed from VB.Net). `myObject = "abc"` had the effect of setting the default property on the `myObject` object. You had to use `Let` to be able to re-assign variables.